# IK Stretching Without Deformation

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

I was wondering if it were possible to setup an IK stretch on a bone so that it only extends along the Y axis and doesn't inflate/shrink the mesh, just extends it; as if I were moving the bone it were connected to in Edit mode. I was looking at a couple different similar questions/videos online, but none of them seemed to be what I was looking for.

I attached images of what it currently does and what I'd like the bone to behave like as it does in Edit mode.

Any help would be appreciated.[image: current deformation issue (notice inflation in 2nd frame)]

[image: the stretching effect I would like to achieve]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222261/stretch-to-constraint-with-uniform-scaling-instead-of-stretching-deforming/222264#222264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an extra deformation bone that has the same location, rotation and **only** the Y-scale of your stretchy bone. You can do this with a driver as well.
[image]

[image]

I also recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PSj_1-E9uY) which will explain more about how squash and stretch rigs can be made in Blender. This person recommends using separate control and deformation rigs, since that's better for games, but it's possible to combine the two like I've done for this post.

Rigging can get pretty complex and dependent on circumstances so I'll provide the file so that you can have a look at it and apply what's relevant to your rig.

[image]

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you so much. Perfectly simple and does exactly what I needed. I saw that exact video but wanted to see if there were other methods, such as this, before I gave it a shot - so thanks again.